# How to abort transaction if filter returns 0 matching document in MongoDB using Go

Tags: mongodb, go

The situation is I have a set list of purchased items with purchase qty (or inventory), and I want to decrease matching product quantity in Catalog collection by the purchase qty. So if there are 10 product1 in catalog collection and one of the purchased `items` is also product1, then the resulted qty will be 10 - `items.Qty`. To achieve this, I do a bulkWrite in a transaction for each updateOne of matching product, do a `filter` operation to get the matching product + check if there's enough qty in the inventory, then decrease the qty.

The thing is I want to make the updateOne operations atomic, in a sense that if even just 1 product doesn't have enough quantity in the inventory to be decreased, i.e. the `filter` operation returns 0 matching document, the transaction should be aborted and earlier updateOne operations should be rolled back.

CMIIW, but I think in my current implementation if the `SetFilter` operation returns 0 matching document, the bulk write still continues to execute the rest of updateOne ops. How to prevent that?

```
func UpdateProducts(ctx context.Context, items []model.Product) (error){
    
    var operations []mongo.WriteModel
    
    // Create transaction function
    callback := func(sessCtx mongo.SessionContext) (interface{}, error) {
        // Create new update operation for each cart item
        for _, item := range items {
            operation := mongo.NewUpdateOneModel()
            operation.SetFilter(
                bson.D{
                    {Key: "_id", Value: item.Product_id}, 
                    {Key: "qty", Value: bson.M{"$gte": item.Qty}},
                },
            ).SetUpdate(
                bson.D{{Key: "$inc", Value: bson.D{{Key: "qty", Value: item.Qty * -1}}}},
            )

            operations = append(operations, operation)
        }
        
        _, err := catalogCollection.BulkWrite(
            context.Background(),
            operations,
        )
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("order creation failed: %v", err)
        }

        return struct{}{}, nil
    }
    // Start a transaction session
    session, err := dbConn.StartSession()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer session.EndSession(ctx)

    _, err = session.WithTransaction(ctx, callback)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Doesn't BulkWrite return the number of document successfully update?

Comment: @Joe Ahh, I guess that means I just need to add this line after bulkwrite and it should be enough right?

if int(res.ModifiedCount) != len(items) {
 sessCtx.AbortTransaction(ctx)
}